# ¿Cómo indexar en google mi pagina de google sites con dominio personalizado?

Tags: google-sites

Adquirí en godaddy el dominio abogadosmartinezco.com, creé un sitio en google sites y luego le ingresé el dominio personalizado. El problema que tengo es que al parecer no es posible para google indexar mi página. Ya estoy en search console, ya estoy en analytics y sigue el mismo inconveniente, alguien me podría orientar?

Lo máximo a lo que llegué es que el archivo robots.exe no permite que google encuentre mi sitio pero por ser google site no tengo forma de modificar ese archivo.

Answer (score 0):

(lo copié de la página de ayuda de google)

Utilizar un dominio personalizado en un sitio web
Nota: Para usar un dominio personalizado de tu cuenta de trabajo o de centro educativo, ponte en contacto con tu administrador.

Puedes usar un dominio personalizado con un sitio publicado en la nueva versión de Google Sites. Si utilizas un dominio personalizado, los usuarios podrán encontrar y recordar tu sitio más fácilmente con una dirección web como [www.tudominio.com](http://www.tudominio.com).

Si quieres utilizar un dominio personalizado con tu sitio, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Seleccionar un dominio de tu cuenta de Google Domains (en caso de tenerlo).
Usar un dominio propio que esté registrado en otro lugar.
Comprar un dominio con Google Domains.
Importante: Solo el propietario de un sitio puede conectarse a un dominio. Más información sobre cómo cambiar el propietario de un sitio

Configurar un dominio personalizado
Ve a Configuración.
Haz clic en Dominios personalizados.
Haz clic en Empezar configuración.
Selecciona una de las opciones que se muestran abajo y sigue los pasos adicionales.
Nota: Puedes conectar hasta cinco dominios personalizados a un sitio. Los cambios que hagas en tu dominio pueden tardar hasta 48 horas en mostrarse en Internet.

Seleccionar un dominio de una cuenta de Google Domains
Utilizar un dominio propio que se haya registrado en otro lugar
Comprar un dominio con Google Domains
Verificar la propiedad de un dominio
Ve a Google Search Console.
En el panel de navegación, elige Añadir propiedad o Buscar una propiedad.
Haz clic en Añadir propiedad.
En la opción Dominio (no en Prefijo de la URL), introduce el dominio que quieres verificar. Por ejemplo, midominio.com.
Haz clic en Continuar.
Sigue las instrucciones de "Cualquier proveedor de DNS".
Copia el registro TXT que proporciona Google Search Console y añádelo a tus registros DNS.
Una vez que hayas añadido el registro TXT a tus registros DNS, haz clic en Verificar.
Eliminar un dominio personalizado
Ve a Configuración.
Haz clic en Dominios personalizados.
Haz clic en el icono de la papelera situado junto al dominio que quieras eliminar.
Cuando se te indique, haz clic en Eliminar para confirmar la acción.
Responder a un mensaje de error
Si ves alguno de los siguientes mensajes de error, sigue estas sugerencias para solucionar el problema:

"DNS no válido": debes añadir un registro CNAME. Consulta cómo redirigir tu dominio a Google Sites. Si ya has actualizado el DNS, espera entre 24 y 48 horas e inténtalo de nuevo.
"No se ha podido comprobar la URL. Cámbiala e inténtalo de nuevo": vuelve a introducir tu URL personalizada y haz clic en Asignar.
"Esta URL no es válida": asegúrate de que has escrito la dirección web completa correctamente. La URL debe incluir un subdominio, como "www".
"Otro servicio de Google ya está utilizando esta URL": otro servicio (como Blogger, la versión clásica de Sites o AppEngine) ya está usando este sitio. Elimina la asignación actual antes de asignar tu URL a un sitio web de Google Sites.
"Este sitio web ya está usando esta URL": tu URL personalizada ya está enlazada a este sitio web creado con Google Sites.
"A esta URL le falta el certificado": elimina tu URL personalizada e intenta asignarla de nuevo. Consulta cómo eliminar la URL.
"Esta URL no está verificada. Verificar la propiedad": consulta cómo verificar tu sitio.
"Has alcanzado el número máximo de URLs de este dominio": tu URL se puede asignar 20 veces a la semana como máximo.
Si tu dominio personalizado deja de funcionar
Puede que tu dominio personalizado deje de funcionar en los siguientes casos:

Si eliminas tu sitio web creado con Google Sites.
Si transfieres la propiedad de tu sitio a otra persona.
Si mueves tu sitio a una unidad de equipo.
Artículos relacionados
¿Quién es mi administrador?
Invitar a otros usuarios a editar tu sitio web
Publicar y compartir tu sitio web
Compartir la gestión de dominios

Comment: Hola, @Manty07. Debes resumir la información que has tomado de la documentación de Google y dejar su referencia. NO se recomienda dejar una copia literal de otra publicación.